# Wave header explaination

Tags: audio, wav

Can someone please explain the following Wave header?

`"RIFFJ\xCB\x9E\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00""D\xAC\x00\x00\x10\xB1\x02\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00""dataD\xCA\x9E\x00"`

I read some answers on the same but was not able to get this out. I have RIFFJ instead of the RIFF and why is there only 4 bit D present instead of 8 bits. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

The J is the first part of the next section, convert back from J to hex we get `4A` so the next sequence to define block size is as follows:
`4A CB 9E 00 or 125858240`.

This looks fairly standard, it appears to fit into the standard explanation of the wave header from here (Although i havent converted the whole thing to check): http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

When you are only given one character from a hex pair, instead of two there is a good chance that it needs converted back to Hex, this will give you the correct number of bits per section!